# What is the fix for 'No p gain specified for pid. Namespace: /gazebo_ros_control/pid_gains/back_right_wheel_joint ' ros melodic?

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,
I am using gazebo_ros_control package from ROS melodic. I am geting error like

```
[ERROR] [1528754765.222507207, 9.660000000]: No p gain specified for pid.  Namespace: /gazebo_ros_control/pid_gains/back_right_wheel_joint
```

I believe I may need to change something in yaml file but I am quite not sure what do I need to change. Can somebody please point me out?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/19667/what-is-the-fix-for-%27no-p-gain-specified-for-pid.-namespace:-/gazebo_ros_control/pid_gains/back_right_wheel_joint-%27-ros-melodic?/) by [rahul](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2334/rahul/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 53 on 2018-06-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) on 2018-06-12**:
Could you please provide some links and instructions to the code you are using and the command you are running? Thanks.

**Comment by [rahul](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2334/rahul/) on 2018-06-15**:
Thanks for answering this. But I got a solution to my problem after finding this example: https://git.univ-bpclermont.fr/laurent.malaterre/local_a7/blob/25304fd5391af87a951e04e36239e885798d7911/ipcar_robot/config/controllers.yaml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I got the solution to my problem by following this example: https://git.univ-bpclermont.fr/laurent.malaterre/local_a7/blob/25304fd5391af87a951e04e36239e885798d7911/ipcar_robot/config/controllers.yaml

---

Originally posted by [rahul](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2334/rahul/) with karma: 53 on 2018-06-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0